# How to prevent from DOS attacks?

Tags: lan, denial-of-service

I live in a college hostel, some other guys do the DOS attacks on rest computers.

The PC gets hanged, CPU uses becomes 100%.

Please help me to prevent from such attacks.

Comment: Ask net admin to monitor in switch/router level

Comment: Start by not giving out your IP address, then make sure every website you visit uses https not http. Or just use a VPN... See [this](http://www.applicure.com/solutions/prevent-denial-of-service-attacks)

Comment: Figure out which room they're at, bring a wrench or baseball bat ?

Comment: one thing could be to ask your net admin for help. another would be to get a firewall and properly configure it. third, and more complicate (difficult to implement), would be to have a vpn server outisde de net, and route all your traffic through that vpn, giving you only one UDP port open to the college network (warning: this probably goes against the college's network policy)

Comment: I just realized this question is entirely off-topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more elaborate solution would be to put some sort of firewall between you and the rest of your network. and if you now where the attacks are coming from, meaning which ip(s) send the traffic you can block those so your computer doesn't even treat them.

Comment: Thank you so much !!!

can you suggest any firewall ?


And how to send traffic to a particular IP address ?